# Hibernate not working on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: kernel

My computer supports hibernation and it hibernation finely worked on Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 and now I am using Ubuntu 13.04 x32bit and I have tried every method for enabling hibernation option but nothing seems to be worked...  I have also tried `sudo pm-hibernate` command for checking hibernation and every thing seems perfectly

Please anyone, can tell how could I get hibernate option.

Comment: Please, take a look at my blog post on this issue http://arecordon.blogspot.com.ar/2013/08/ubuntu-enabling-hibernation.html